# set random images in multiple div sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery grid that has four div containers. I want to enclose whatever image inside the divs, keeping in mind that each div box has a different height and width. The should be centered in the div leaving reasonable padding on all sides. Please check the link to get a better understanding  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dajin007/s4ykz/)
http://d.alistapart.com/fluid-images/3-4.png

Any help is highly appreciated.
    enter code here

```
 <div id="body">
  <div class="container">
<img class="magic" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-2wtTsHn/0/M/JLF_3559-M.jpg">          
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="container h2">
    <img class="magic" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-2wtTsHn/0/M/JLF_3559-M.jpg">
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="container h3">
    <img class="magic" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-2wtTsHn/0/M/JLF_3559-M.jpg">
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="container w2">
    <img class="magic" src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-2wtTsHn/0/M/JLF_3559-M.jpg">
</div>
```

```
 .container {
  height:100px;
   width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  background: #CCC;
   border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: 4px 0 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
     }
  .magic {
   max-width:90%;
   height:70%;
   }
   .h2 {
  height: 210px;
   width: 220px;
    }
  #body {
    margin: 10px;
   }
 .h3 {
  width: 340px;
  height: 210px;
  } 
  .w2 {
    width: 220px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understood your problem... if you use

```
.magic {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

with big pictures what is the problem ?

you want them to fill the entire div AND respecting theire size ratio ?

Comment: the idea is to pull images stored in Database, and dynamically fit them in div containers that have different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding these images as a background-image property to a block-level div, such as:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="magic" style="background-image: url(SOURCEHERE.JPG)"></div>
</div>
```

With additional CSS like:

```
.container{
    width: 100px; /* or some other width */
    height: 100px; /* or some other height */
    padding:20px; /* this will add a little margin around your image */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* padding will be calculated with the container dimensions */
}

.magic{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PDL2U/

Comment: this will not work if we apply it to multiple images that vary in terms width and height.

Comment: This will work regardless of image width and height! Contain will always apply a best-fit for the content vs. the containing element.